# Endless Scroll Listener

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I'm new in java and I was reading about listviews so 
If I am right, It will consume the memory of a device if a listview has thousands of items so to avoid that I should create a scroll listener that would load more itens each time that x items have already been loaded. Right?

I have found this code and I am trying to use it but in the main activity when I try to implement it and set the onLoadMOre, I don't know what to do.

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
        this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
        this.currentPage = startPage;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount)
    {
        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; }
        }
        // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            currentPage++;
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Don't take any action on changed
    }
}
```

MyCode:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements EndlessScrollListener{

    List<Paises> paisesList = new ArrayList<Paises>();
    EditText j_search;

    ListView j_listview;

    String[] j_paises;
    String[] j_nota;

  PaisesAdapter j_adapter;


    int[] j_flags  =
            {
                    R.drawable.flag_brazil,
                    R.drawable.flag_bolivia,
                    R.drawable.flag_argentina,
                    R.drawable.flag_chile,
                    R.drawable.flag_colombia,
                    R.drawable.flag_equador,
                    R.drawable.flag_france,
                    R.drawable.flag_guyana,
                    R.drawable.flag_paraguay,
                    R.drawable.flag_peru,
                    R.drawable.flag_suriname,
                    R.drawable.flag_uruguay,
                    R.drawable.flag_venezuela

            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        j_paises = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.r_arrayPais);
        j_nota = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.r_arrayNota);

        j_listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.l_lView);
        j_search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.l_searchView);

        j_adapter = new PaisesAdapter(this, paisesList);


        j_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        j_listview.setAdapter(j_adapter);
        j_listview.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);


        int i = 0;
        for(String paises : j_paises)
        {
            Paises dataProvider = new Paises(j_flags[i], paises, j_nota[i]);
            j_adapter.add(dataProvider);
            i++;
        }

        Collections.sort(paisesList, new AbcComparator());

        j_listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        j_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");
                j_adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {

    }


}
```

Comment: you don't know what should do  in `onLoadMore`??

Comment: yes, i dont know what I should put ther.

Comment: `onLoadMore` you should get a new set of data and put it into the adapter, and call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` to refresh data. do you find sample code of it?

Comment: So I should use a asyncTask to populate my adapter and get it back onLoadmore?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you need to deal with items stored in the adapter. 
The adapter is the one which deals with the list of models (items, data).

So hypothetically, if your adapter

- extends [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)
- has a getter/setter to update its list of items `MyAdapter.getItems()/setItems(List<Item> newItems)`
- and you have a reference to use either to your adapter or the list view, then

  ```
  @Override
  public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
      // download or fetch next page(s) items, then add them to your adapter list
      List<Item> newPageOfItems = .....;

      // if list view reference, cast and get a reference to your adapter
      MyAadapter myAdapter = (MyAdapter) listView.getAdapter();

      if (newPageOfItems != null && !newPageOfItems.isEmpty()) {
          List<Item> currentItems = myAdapter.getItems();
          currentItems.addAll(newPageOfItems);
          currentItems.setItems(currentItems);
          // if for some reason new page is not updated properly, uncomment below
          // myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  }
  ```